# OpenERP 7 standard addons adding generates error "No handler found"

Tags: windows, bazaar, add-on, openerp-7, launchpad

I used `openerp-allinone-setup-7.0-latest.exe` to install OpenERP 7 in windows platform.
I fetched latest version from `LunchPad` repository `~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk` using `Bazaar`.

I copied trunk addons folders to `C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20140324-001327\Server\server\openerp\addons` then restarted OpenERP service

Then, when I enter `localhost:8069` I get `No handler found` error!!

Any help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked log to find that one of web addons generated an error. So I removed it.